# What are the advantages of `do {…} until` over `do {…} while`?

Tags: language-design

I wrote an answer for
[pros cons - What are the advantages of providing an until loop construct?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-are-the-advantages-of-providing-an-until-loop-construct/726).
The ambiguous question was later updated, making it clear that I had misinterpreted it.

It asks about `while (…) {…}` versus `until (…) {…}`, with the condition at the top.
This question is about `do {…} while (…)` versus `do {…} until (…)`, with the condition at the end.

So, rather than waste my answer, I'll ask the question I thought I'd answered.

What are the advantages of `do {…} until` over `do {…} while`?

Comment: IMO this should be dupe hammered, as the only difference between that and this question is the addition of a ‘do‘, and if you did your algebra, you will know doing this to both loops cancels out (a math joke but I'm serious)

Comment: @Seggan. How can this be rejected as a duplicate when the answer was rejected as inappropriate for that "duplicate"?

Comment: Because the questions are very closely linked, the only difference is the addition of the do, which doesn't change much

Comment: @Seggan, No, that's not the difference. The first question is about `while (…) {…}` versus `until (…) {…}`, with the condition at the beginning of the block. This is about `do {…} while (…)` versus `do {…} until (…)`, with the condition at the *end* of the block.

Comment: @user16217248, no it doesn't. I refer to that question in the first line of this question. My answer was rejected for that first question, so how can it possibly be a duplicate?

Comment: I understand the difference, however the difference applied does not change most of the answers

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
while (condition) {
    ...
}

do {
    ...
} until (condition)
```

The condition before the block decides whether to do what follows.
The condition after the block decides whether to stop doing what preceded.

Both feel natural, but having a `while` at the *end* of the block feels awkward.

Even worse, consider this (non-standard style) code:

```
    ...
}
while (condition)
{
    ...
```

Which kind of `while` is that?
It's impossible to say from the immediate context.

Overloading keywords isn't always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Both `while` and `until` allow for writing the same loops, since the condition can always be negated by the logical `not`/`!` operator. But I think `while(not something)` reads much better than `until(not something)`, so if a language has only one then `while` is better than `until`. The latter is not *exactly* a double negative, but it's close enough that it requires more thinking for me at least.

So the argument for `do`/`until` being more natural rests on this kind of loop being used more commonly with "negative" conditions rather than "positive" conditions, so that the negation implicit in `until` doesn't have to be cancelled out with another negation. This seems like something that should be answerable empirically, but I would expect that `do`/`while` with "positive" conditions is at least roughly as common in real code as it is with "negative" conditions.

There are also some conditions like `length > 0` vs. `length == 0` where the condition is negated without needing a "not" or "not equal" operator. Personally I think `while(length > 0)` is more natural than `until(length == 0)`, but it probably makes sense to exclude cases like this from consideration since they aren't a "win" for either option.

Of course, a language could easily have both `while` and `until`, with relatively little extra work for the implementation; one can be [syntax sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the other.